# Performing post-hoc comparisons with emmeans for model of class 'mixed' does not work

Tags: r, mixed-models, pairwise, emmeans

I ran the following mixed model:

```
fit_mixed_POST <- mixed(correct~probability_simple*letter_position+
(1|PP),data=all_data_cleaned_POST_only, method = c("LRT"),
family=(binomial(link = "logit")))
```

Now, I would like to perform all pairwise comparisons for probability_simple and letter_position using emmeans.
However, when trying to run (after introducing the library(emmeans):

```
emmeans(fit_mixed_POST, "probability_simple")
```

I get following error:

```
Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : Can't handle an object of class  “mixed”
```

However, emmeans should support the performed mixed model, according to the documentation. The mixed model is part of the afex package, and they mention  that mixed objects should be supported.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

According to the list of [models supported by `emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) `mixed` models from the `afex` package are supported directly through the `afex` package.

We can verify the calculation of marginal means from the `mixed` model fit, using one of the sample datasets included in `afex`

```
library(afex)
library(emmeans)

data(md_15.1)
model <- mixed(iq ~ timecat + (1 + time|id), data = md_15.1)

emmeans(model, "timecat")
# timecat emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
# 30         103 4.14 12.3     94.0      112
# 36         107 3.88 14.8     98.7      115
# 42         110 3.91 14.8    101.6      118
# 48         112 4.23 12.2    102.8      121
#
#Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
#Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Thank you for checking. Weird, it does work with lmer, but for some reason will not accept mixed.

Comment: @KnRm Does the example code I give with `mixed` work for you? Perhaps you need to update `afex` and/or `emmeans`. The code above works for `emmeans_1.3.2` and `afex_0.24-1`.

Comment: @KnRm Do you have both emmeans and afex loaded?

Comment: Thank you for the responses. yes, I have them both loaded. it works perfectly when including a glmer-model. my version of emmeans is 1.4, could that be the problem?

Comment: @KnRm I've just checked, and everything works fine with `emmeans_1.4`. Can you please clearly (i.e. yes/no) confirm whether the example I give above works for you? Copy and paste the code and you should be able to reproduce the output I give above. Make sure you load the libraries (as I do). This **definitely** works for `afex_0.24.1` and `emmeans_1.3.2`/`emmeans_1.4`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I tried your example, gives me the same error as I previously encountered: 
    `Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : 
   Can't handle an object of class  “mixed” 
   Use help("models", package = "emmeans") for information on supported
   models.` Not sure what it could be. Fitting of the model works perfectly, emmeans does not.

Comment: @KnRm That is very strange. And you have `afex_0.24.1`? Have you tried this from a fresh R terminal?

Comment: @KnRm That's an anticlimactic conclusion. Anyway, one for the ["have you tried turning it off and on again"](https://media.giphy.com/media/rcOlpTCkM1GAE/giphy.gif) books. Consider closing the question by setting the tick mark.